# Aframe not loading image from local path in angular and arjs

Tags: angular, typescript, image, augmented-reality, aframe

I am trying to load a image from the local path. The code is in app.component.html in angular.
here is my code:

```
  <a-scene embedded arjs>
      <a-assets>
          <img id="test_img" src="/mnt/r/flipkart/proj/src/app/abcd.jpg">
      </a-assets>
      <a-marker preset="hiro" url="hiro.patt">
          <a-image 
              rotation="90 0 0"
              src="#test_img"></a-image>
              <!-- <a-image 
              rotation="90 0 0"
              src="#imge" id="baba"></a-image> -->
      </a-marker>
      <a-entity camera></a-entity>
      <div style='position: fixed; top: 10px; width:100%; text-align: center; z-index: 1;'>
        <button (click)="hideme()">
            HIDE OBJECTS
        </button>
    </div>
  </a-scene>
```

On console I am getting this message:

```
GET http://localhost:4200/mnt/r/flipkart/proj/src/app/abcd.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

how can I get it to avoid making a get request and just use the images from a local folder.

Comment: Are these images/files exist on server, on  relevant location `mnt/r/flipkart/proj/src/app/abcd.jpg`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can I get it to avoid making a get request

You can specify, that you want to use the `file://` protocol, ie: `file:///mnt/r/flipkart/proj/src/app/abcd.jpg`

**ALTHOUGH** images, videos or audio loaded via the `file` protocol, [won't work with `a-frame` due to cross-origin policies](https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/introduction/faq.html#why-does-my-asset-e-g-image-video-model-not-load). If you're developing locally, you will still need a server to host assets.

The [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/introduction/installation.html#use-a-local-server) recommend:

- with node - [five-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/five-server)
- with python - the default `SimpleHTTPServer` module